# "cannot instantiate abstract class" Multiple inheritance and 3rd party interface

Tags: c++

I have an existing project with the following class inheritance

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base();
    virtual ~Base();    
    void    SetID(unsigned short);
    virtual inline unsigned short GetID();
    protected:      
    unsigned short  id;
};


class Generic : public Base {
public:
        Generic(const char  *in_name);
        const   char* GetName()                 { return name; }

    protected:  
        char    name[30];
};

class Actor : public Generic
{
public:     
    Actor(const char    *in_name);
    ~Actor();   
    void DoSomething(const char* str);   
};
```

Now i created a separate project were i want to provide an interface that has to be implemented in order to use the functionality - i plan on reusing this project for other implementation.

```
class MyInterface
{
    public:     
        virtual ~MyInterface() {} 

        // Our methods that need to implemented
        virtual const char* GetName() = 0;      
        virtual void DoSomething(const char* str) = 0;
        virtual unsigned short GetID() = 0;
};
```

Now i simply wanted to use this with my actor class e.g. 
    class Actor : public Generic, public MyInterface

however it fails to compile

```
'const char *MyInterface::GetName(void)' : is abstract see declaration of     'MyInterface::GetName'
'unsigned short MyInterface::GetID(void)' : is abstract see declaration of 'MyInterface::GetID'
error C2385: ambiguous access of 'GetName'
could be the 'GetName' in base 'Generic'
or could be the 'GetName' in base 'MyInterface'
```

The problem is probably that GetName is already implemented in Generic, and GetID is already implemented in Base - so in the child class Actor implementing the Interface is not possible because the compiler is not smart enough to realize there is already an implementation of these methods.

However, i found a workaround - but for this i would have to extend the header of the actor class which is not a nice thing - and i wanted to know if there is another approach - my fix is

```
class Actor : public Generic, public MyInterface
{
public:     
    Actor(const char    *in_name);
    ~Actor();   
    void DoSomething(const char* str);   
    const char* GetName() { return Generic::GetName(); };
    inline unsigned short GetID() { return Base::GetID(); };
};
```

Now this obviously will not work for varargs methods and i would have to implement existing methods and delegate to the parent again - is there a better solution?

**EDIT** For clarifications - the classes base,generic and actor exist in another project managed by others, modifications to these should be very limited. - I created a seperate project which creates a static LIB - to use functions of these in conjunction with the actor class - i created an interface to not have any dependency in my own project and also provide a reusable lib for other projects which would simply just need to implement this interface.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why you're trying to inject a second orthogonal interface into `Actor`? That would help us invent possible solutions.

Comment: Please explain *why* `MyInterface` exists, and what it's true relationship to the other classes is.  As it stands, this design looks completely broken.

Comment: *the compiler is not smart enough to realize*... The language mandates what the compiler can/must do. In this case, the two functions are not overrides according to the language and thus you need to implement it.

Comment: @Mark B and John Dibling i updated the description to be more clear about it - also the design is "not completely" broken - thats a normal design pattern in the java world

Comment: A tip, don't mention java when talking to c++ people ;) I kid of course :)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the compiler not being smart enough. You simply have two distinct base functions with the same name and signature, and so the inheritance is ambiguous.

Comment: @Steve But please don't try to write Java in the C++ language. It'll subvert both languages to do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Base
{
protected:      
    unsigned short  id;
public:
    void SetID(unsigned short);
    virtual inline unsigned short GetID() { return id; }
    virtual ~Base() {}
    Base(): id() {}
};


class Generic 
    : public Base
{
protected:  
    char    name[30];
public:
    const char* GetName() { return name; }
    Generic(const char* in_name): name() {}
};

class Actor
    : public Generic
{
public:     
    void DoSomething(const char* str) {}

    ~Actor() {}
    Actor(const char* in_name)
        : Generic( name )
    {}
};

class MyInterface
{
public:     
    // Our methods that need to implemented
    virtual const char* name() const = 0;      
    virtual int id() const = 0;
    virtual void doSomething( const char* str ) = 0;

    virtual ~MyInterface() {} 
};

template< class TpBase >
class MyInterfaceOn
    : public virtual MyInterface
    , public TpBase
{
public:
    typedef TpBase Base;

private:
    MyInterfaceOn& mutableSelf() const
    { return *const_cast<MyInterfaceOn*>( this ); }

public:
    const char* name() const { return mutableSelf().Base::GetName(); }
    int id() const { return mutableSelf().Base::GetID(); }
    void doSomething(const char* str) { Base::DoSomething( str ); }

    MyInterfaceOn( char const name[] )
        : Base( name )
    {}
};

class MyActor
    : public MyInterfaceOn< Actor >
{
public:
    MyActor( char const name[] )
        : MyInterfaceOn< Actor >( name )
    {}
};

int main()
{
    MyInterface const&  actor   = MyActor( "NN" );
}
```

Comment: +1 Other than the non-const accessors that exist in the original code I think this solves the problem as laid out.

Comment: Thanks, but as far as i read this solution - it means that in the whole project code not managed by me - Actor instantiation and handling has to be replaced with the class MyActor -whereas my original solution only requires that i specify which method from which parent should be used - i dont see the enhancement here?

Comment: @Steve: if you're saying that you want existing code to use an unchanged `Actor` class, and at the same time that the `Actor` class should be changed in some way, well that's just self-contradictory. If you're saying that you want to provide an interface on top of existing instances of `Actor`, then just do the same as above but instead of inheriting, forward to an existing instance. It's difficult to guess from your description, sorry.

Comment: I want to limit the changes to a minimum - my current "workaround" is just adding methods which overwrite the methods from the base class - there is no change anywhere in the code needed for this. The solution provided by you - means that everywhere an actor is instantiated or handled, or casted in the existing codebase, needs to be modified to the new class "MyActor"

Comment: @Steve: sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Your solution introduces a new class MyActor - correct? Since the original codebase is only using the Actor class - all references where the old Actor class is instantiated needs to be modified to us the new MyActor class - that means, outside of the header file additionally changes need to be made - where as the original solution i provided only requires modifying the header of Actor and adding a new method GetID which simply proxies the call to  Base:GetID method